# What is the difference between global-set-key and local-set-key?

Tags: key-bindings, prefix-keys

I want to make a prefix key. So which command is better for making a prefix key?

REF:

- https://www.emacswiki.org/emacs/PrefixKey

Comment: Newcomers to Emacs keybindings are well advised to read this excellent article: https://www.masteringemacs.org/article/mastering-key-bindings-emacs (it's way more information than you're asking for, but it will answer a ton of questions that you haven't asked yet).

Comment: @phils Thx for your advice :)

Comment: @Drew Edited. That means making a prefix key.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The short answer:

If you wish the prefix to be present in all buffers and all modes, use `global-set-key`. If you wish it to be present only in one mode, use `local-set-key`.

The difference between the two is what keymap they put the binding into: The global one, or the local one. When you type a key sequence, the local map is searched first, then the global one. So a binding in the local map could shadow the global binding. Each major mode typically defines its own local map, which is shared among all buffers using that mode.

There is much more to say about keymaps and keymap searching, but this should be a good start.

Comment: Do you mean that the choice is based on modes or a mode?

Comment: If you mean *your* choice of which one to use, it depends how you are going to use it.